# Label placement overlapping

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, layers, overlapping-features

[image]

Is there a way to prevent labels from 2 different layers (province and city names)? This map of Argentina looks a bit messy as some labels are overlapping and become unreadable.

Comment: And you are doing this using which software?

Comment: You need to find a base map with no names on it

Comment: Try setting a lower priority for the labels you wish to be hidden if they overlap

Comment: @ Erik, I am using QGIS 3.4    @ Ian see my comments below. @ MrXsquared will follow your advise. To all I am very grateful for your kind assistance, it helps me a lot to learn how to use QGIS. For a absolute rockbottom beginner, it is not easy. Many thanks. S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QGIS will try to not overlap labels when possible but as you experience it's not always possible with some settings. To prevent overlapping labels you can try (listed in no particular order) to:

- Choose a more relaxed label placement (ie. choose a setting that
  allow the labelling engine to choose between more possible placements)
- uncheck the "show all label for all layers" in the labelling engine
  setting (but you won't have all labels, you could use the "priority"
  slider on each layer label setting to choose witch one will be
  displayed over the other)
- increase the "number of candidate" in the labelling engine setting
  (it's the number of different position that the engine will evaluate
  for label placement, I'm not sure of the exact effect of that)
- Have smaller/more compact label (use smaller font size or multi-line
  label, play with character width and spacing...)
- manually place the label at the best location (on the map with complex
  labelling this is often the only way to get good placement, on
  your map as you don't have that many labels it may be quicker than
  playing with all the above settings...)
- tolerate some superposition, if some label are a less important place
  those less important labels at the bottom (under the other label, use
  the "label z index" setting to order your label by layer) and choose
  a combination of font and color that make the upper label legible
  (like bigger black label on top of a smaller grey label)

If you want to read on label placement : [Positioning Names on Maps - by Eduard Imhof](https://www.reddit.com/r/mapmaking/comments/5tbc1u/resource_positioning_names_on_maps_by_eduard_imhof/)  (**EDIT:** this was a google drive link to the pdf on a Reddit page but the google drive link is now dead...)

Comment: Thank you @J.R. much appreciate, I ended up moving the labels manually!

Comment: the referenced google drive link no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS can only control labels that it is drawing, it looks like the basemap you are using has the labels pre-drawn on it before it is added to QGIS so that QGIS thinks it is just an image and knows nothing about the labels.

The only fix for this is to use another base map with no labels or replace that layer with a set of layers that QGIS is drawing so it can combine the labels and work out label placements for you.

Comment: Hi Ian, when you say "pre-drawn" does that include shape files. i.e. is a shape file a "pre-drawn file in your words? The map is made of 3 shape file layers, city, province and country. Would layers talk to each other and arrange labels in the best possible way ? (if that makes sense). Thank you for your help, much appreciated

Comment: A shapefile would be ideal