# Automatically move overlapping labels from multiple layers and features

Tags: qgis, labeling, mapping

So I am currently making a overview of a water system including manholes and pipelines. However, in some situations the parts are so small that the labels are overlapping. (see picture below) I tried moving the labels by hand using the data-defined placement and call out lines, however, this would take a lot of time for the whole water system. Is there a way QGIS can do this automatically?[image]

Comment: You could try to set your label further from your point with cartographic placement and activate leader line, QGIS should then try to avoid overlap (see this for some more labeling suggestion https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358525/label-placement-overlapping/358539#358539)

Comment: @J.R this is a very helpfull answer that you link, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing `layer properties > Labels > Placement > Obstacles` there you choose **Features act as obstacles** and set the **Obstacle Weight** a bit higher in the `settings`.
[image]

A word of caution here: you may need to try around a bit. How this will look obviously depends also on the zoom-level at which you want to display your map.

Lastly the **Priority** will determine the placement of labels from different layers (i.e. which label will be prioritized etc.)